# How to apply custom function to pandas data frame for each row

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply a custom function and create a derived column called population2050 that is based on two columns already present in my data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('factbook.db')
query = "select * from facts where area_land =0;"
facts = pd.read_sql_query(query,conn)
print(list(facts.columns.values))

def final_pop(initial_pop,growth_rate):
    final = initial_pop*math.e**(growth_rate*35)
    return(final)

facts['pop2050'] = facts['population','population_growth'].apply(final_pop,axis=1)
```

When I run the above code, I get an error. Am I not using the 'apply' function correctly?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Apply will pass you along the entire row with axis=1. Adjust like this assuming your two columns are called `initial_pop`and `growth_rate`

```
def final_pop(row):
    return row.initial_pop*math.e**(row.growth_rate*35)
```

Comment: This will result: `TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index`...

Answer (score 37):

You were almost there:

```
facts['pop2050'] = facts.apply(lambda row: final_pop(row['population'],row['population_growth']),axis=1)
```

Using lambda allows you to keep the specific (interesting) parameters listed in your function, rather than bundling them in a 'row'.

Answer (score 30):

Your function,

```
def function(x):
  // your operation
  return x
```

call your function as,

```
df['column']=df['column'].apply(function)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve the same result without the need for `DataFrame.apply()`. Pandas series (or dataframe columns) can be used as direct arguments for NumPy functions and even built-in Python operators, which are applied element-wise. In your case, it is as simple as the following:

```
import numpy as np

facts['pop2050'] = facts['population'] * np.exp(35 * facts['population_growth'])
```

This multiplies each element in the column `population_growth`, applies numpy's `exp()` function to that new column (`35 * population_growth`) and then adds the result with `population`.