# fillna() not allowing floating values

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, imputation, fillna

I'm testing a simple imputation method on the side using a copy of my dataset. I'm essentially trying to impute missing values with categorical means grouped by the target variable.

```
df_test_2 = train_df.loc[:,['Survived','Age']].copy()  #copy of dataset for testing

#creating impute function
def impute(df,variable):
    if 'Survived'==0: df[variable] = df[variable].fillna(30.7)
    else: df[variable] = df[variable].fillna(28.3)

#imputing
impute(df_test_2,'Age')
```

The output is that the imputation is successful, but the values added are 30 and 28 instead of 30.7 and 28.3.
'Age' is float64.

Thank you

Edit: I simply copied the old code for calling the function here and corrected it now. Wasn't the issue in my original code; problem persists.

Comment: You've defined `impute` but are calling `impute_age`. Is it possible `impute_age` refers to some other older version of the function that's still in memory and filled with 30 and 28?

Comment: Besides calling the wrong function you test `'Survived' == 0` which is always `False`. Your question is not reproducible.

Comment: Your function fills every `na` with `28.3`. It does not impute `28`. Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this to see what may be going on

To test it I set up a simple case

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Survived' : [0,1,1,0,0,1], 'Age' :[12.2,45.4,np.nan,np.nan,64.3,44.3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

This got the data set

```
    Survived    Age
0   0           12.2
1   1           45.4
2   1           NaN
3   0           NaN
4   0           64.3
5   1           44.3
```

I ran your function exactly

```
def impute(df,variable):
    if 'Survived'==0: df[variable] = df[variable].fillna(30.7)
    else: df[variable] = df[variable].fillna(28.3)
```

and this yielded this result

```
    Survived    Age
0   0.          12.2
1   1           45.4
2   1           28.3
3   0           28.3
4   0           64.3
5   1           44.3
```

As you can see on the index 3 the row age got filled with the wrong value. The problem is this 'Survived'==0. This is always going to be false.  You are checking to see if the string is 0 and it is not.

What you may want is

```
df2 = df[df['Survived'] == 0].fillna(30.7)
df3 = df[df['Survived'] == 1].fillna(28.3)
dfout = df2.append(df3)
```

and the output is

```
    Survived    Age
0   0           12.2
3   0           30.7
4   0           64.3
1   1           45.4
2   1           28.3
5   1           44.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Anish

I think is better to use the method apply() available in pandas. This method applies (in rows or in columns) a custom function over a dataframe.

I let you one post: [Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40353519/how-to-apply-custom-function-to-pandas-data-frame-for-each-row/54145945)

Documentation pandas: [Doc Apply df](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

regards,